# Why can't i return all cimsession functions from Powershell.Invoke() method in c#

Tags: c#, powershell, psobject

I'm running `New-CimSession` command from both Powershell and C#. When I run it on Powershell, CimSession variable has a lot of functions such as `TestConnection()`, `CreateInstance` etc.. Picture is below.

[image]

But, `CimSession` variable type of `PSObject` doesn't have others functions except `ToString()` and `GetType()`, when I run `New-CimSession` command from `Powershell.Invoke()` method in c#.

I want to access same method from `PSObject` variable on c#.
Do you have a idea?

Comment: Hi Emre, Let me know if the solution worked out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add Reference to `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure Namespace`
- Add `using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure;

```
static void Main(string [] args)
{
     var csession = CimSession.Create("");
     csession.TestConnection();
}
```

`csession` will have access to different Methods you want

**Reference here:**

- *"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WMI\v1.0\Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll"*
- *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure*

Comment: Yes, you are right. this way helps but my project is .NET Framework 4.8. I took this error.
"Could not install package 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Runtime.Unix 2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

Comment: Yes, i was trying to use Nuget, but i look at for .dll but there isn't **C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WMI\v1.0"**

Comment: Yes, Windows 10

Comment: really thank you. I found it there. Now, i will try to implement it to project.

Comment: sure great, if it works you can accept my answer !!

Comment: you can click on green tick box next to answer to accept it !!